# What are sized types in Agda?

Tags: types, agda, type-systems, induction, totality

What are sized types in Agda? I've tried to read the paper about [MiniAgda](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1012.4896.pdf), but failed to proceed due to the following points:

1. Why are data types generic over their size? As far as I know the size is the depth of the tree of induction.
2. Why are data types covariant over their size, i.e. i <= j -> T_i <= T_j ?
3. What do the `>` and `#` patterns mean?

Answer (score 9):

1. The idea is that a sized type is just a family of types indexed by sizes, which are essentially ordinals. When defining an inductive type as `sized data`, the compiler checks that the result is a type with the correct size, so that, for example, `succ` in `SNat` increases the size in 1. That way, for a sized type `S` `(i : Size) -> S i` is essentially an element of `S` with size `i`. What looks weird to me is why the definition of zero for `SNat` is `zero : (i : Size) -> SNat ($ i)` instead of something like `zero : (i : Size) -> SNat ($ 0)`.
2. For sized *inductive* types this makes sense, as T_i is the type of elements of T with size *less than* i, so that if i ≤ j then T_i ≤ T_j; constructors must increase the size in recursive calls.
3. As explained in section 2.3, `#` is equivalent to T_∞, the type of elements of T with no known size bound; this is a top element for the T_i's in the subtyping preorder. The pattern (i > j) is used to bind a size j while keeping the information that j < i. The example in the paper for minus makes this clear:

   ```
   fun minus : [i : Size] -> SNat i -> SNat # -> SNat i
   { minus i (zero (i > j)) y = zero j
   ; minus i x (zero .#) = x
   ; minus i (succ (i > j) x) (succ .# y) = minus j x y
   }
   ```

   First the signature means that substracting any number (`SNat #` is a number with no size bound information) from a number of size at most i (that's what `SNat i` means) returns a number of size at most i; and for the `>` pattern, in the last line we use it to match a number of size at most j, and the recursive call type checks because of subtyping: `SNat j ≤ SNat i`.